# como personalizar mi login con spring security 6

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

BuenasTardes, estoy intentado personalizar un login con spring security 6 pero siempre  me sale el formulario por defecto que estare haciendo mal?

anexo coloco el codigo que escribi (configuracion de spring security)

```
   package securityconfig;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class securityconfig {
    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(( authorized) ->authorized  .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .formLogin(form-> form
                           .loginPage("loggin")
                           .loginProcessingUrl("urlprocess")
                           .permitAll()
                          )
                .build();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Si estas usando Thymeleaf y tienes tu LoginController , deberia ser solamente el loginPage y agregar

```
http
            .authorizeHttpRequests("/login",...)
            .formLogin(formLogin ->
                    formLogin
                            .loginPage("/login")
                             ...
            )
```

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, va hacer lo que me indicas